# mmenujs Jquery Menu

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mmenu

I have this (menu.js) working just fine in all browser except IE, I have the polyfil loaded and all other JS removed for testing, but it still refuses to work in IE, any help or pointers would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a [mcve] of the code you are working with?

Comment: Hi, If you have a look at this, https://noted-eland.cloudvent.net in IE you should see the problem, all the js is concatenated into one file, I've tried it with separating the JS file with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I try to download the sample example from [mmenujs.com](https://mmenujs.com/)

I try to run it with IE 11 and it works fine.

[image]

I check it's documentation and found information below.

> As of version 8, the mmenu.js plugin by default only supports
>   ECMAScript 6 compliant browsers. For Internet Explorer 10 and 11,
>   you'll need the JavaScript polyfills included in the package.
>
> Version 7 should work in Internet Explorer 10 and 11 without any
>   shortcomings, it should also work to some degree in Internet Explorer
>   9, but you'll need a matchMedia polyfill.

Reference:

[Supported browsers for mmenu.js](https://mmenujs.com/docs/)

I suggest you to download the sample example from their site and directly try to run it in IE to check whether it is working or not. If it works than you can try to check and compare your code and configuration with their sample.

It may help to find the cause for the issue.

Comment: Hi, I've downloaded the demo and tried to run it locally but it doesn't work in IE, but the website http://www.mmenujs.com works just fine in IE, this has me stuck at the moment. Can't see what the mmenu website is doing differently!

Comment: I try to check your site and the official site of mmenujs in IE 11 browser. I found that Official site of mmenujs is adding the polyfil file and I can see it in their code and also in Network tab in developer tools. But polyfil file is missing in your site. I suggest you to again check whether polyfil was added properly or not. If not than try to add it may help to fix the issue for IE browser.

Comment: Thank you for looking, I've made the change as suggested but still know luck, If you would check again to see what results you are seeing, Thanks

Comment: I again try to check your site in IE browser and I did not see any polyfil.js file. Not sure how you are adding this polyfil. If possible than let us know about that. It may give some idea about the issue.

Comment: I'm using cloud cannon to host the files, they have renamed the Polyfil to https://d1qmdf3vop2l07.cloudfront.net/noted-eland.cloudvent.net/compressed/_min_/0ded22fed56974bfda7c838a1a405c25.js this is the original file from mmenujs just a different name, this must be an automated process they use.

Comment: I again check the site and find that 1 polyfil file is loading but still I did not find any polyfil files referenced in you web page. There is one which is commented. so you can have a check whether you properly referenced in your web page or not.

Comment: Hi Deepak, I've moved a sample away from Cloudcannon to see if that helped, still dose not work in IE, but it should be clearer as to what is and is not loading, new URL http://sneakypeeks.co.uk/fsc/

Comment: https://github.com/FrDH/mmenu-js/archive/master.zip Download the zip file from this link. Extract it. Go to demo folder and try to run the default.html file in IE browser and let us know about the result by providing any short video or GIF file.